# Default selected value not working using ng-init

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-init

Simply trying to make a default selected value in Angular but thus far I am having no luck.

HTML Before Compile:

```
<select ng-options="select.Value as select.Name for select in ruleSelect" ng-model="rule.MatchLogic" ng-init="rule.MatchLogic = 0" ></select>
```

HTML In Browser Source:

```
<select ng-options="select.Value as select.Name for select in ruleSelect" ng-model="rule.MatchLogic" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="0">All</option>
<option value="1">At Least</option>
<option value="2">At Most</option>
</select>
```

How do I make value=0 (All) the default selected value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is set your `ng-model` value `rule.MatchLogic` to equal the corresponding value in the options. The options you use are `ruleSelect`.

So for example, set `rule.MatchLogic = ruleSelect[someSelector].Value;` inside your controller.